# How to document a defmethod function?

Tags: clojure

As described in the [defmethod doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmethod#example-542692c7c026201cdc3269cd), they can be given a name. What is very useful in stack traces.

`(defmethod foo "a" name-of-method [params] "was a")`

When replacing `name-of-method` by a string. I get the following error:

```
:cause "Call to clojure.core/fn did not conform to spec."                          
 :data #:clojure.spec.alpha{:problems ({:path [:fn-tail :arity-1 :params], :pred clo
jure.core/vector?, :val "A documentation", :via [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+bo
dy :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list :clojure.core.specs.alpha/param-list], :in [
0]} {:path [:fn-tail :arity-n], :pred (clojure.core/fn [%] (clojure.core/or (clojure
.core/nil? %) (clojure.core/sequential? %))), :val "A documentation", :via [:clojure
.core.specs.alpha/params+body :clojure.core.specs.alpha/params+body], :in [0]}), :sp
ec #object[clojure.spec.alpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2509 0x24de08c1 "clojure.spec.a
lpha$regex_spec_impl$reify__2509@24de08c1"]
```

So what's the propper way to document a defmethod?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. If you look at the source (`(. ~(with-meta multifn {:tag 'clojure.lang.MultiFn}) addMethod ~dispatch-val (fn ~@fn-tail)))`), `fn-tail` (everything after the first two arguments) is passed directly to `fn`, and afaik, `fn` itself has no notion of documentation. That's why you can give the method a name; because `fn` can accept a name. I think it's expected that the multi is documented instead, and each method is consistent enough that individual documentation isn't necessary.

Comment: You might be able to do something hacky like use `with-meta` on the method object somehow to manually add documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can document the `defmethod` function ***using a symbol*** like the following:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(defmulti ident
  (fn [item] (type item)) )    
;                                        vvvvvv-function-name
(defmethod ident clojure.lang.Keyword  ident-fn-kw  [item]
  "to my heart")
(defmethod ident java.lang.String      ident-fn-str [item]
  "like cheese")
(defmethod ident clojure.lang.Symbol   ident-fn-sym [item]
  "crash, bang"
 ;(throw (ex-info "surprise!" {:reason :dont-need-one}))
   )

(dotest
  (is= clojure.lang.Keyword (spyx (type :hello)))
  (is= java.lang.String (spyx (type "hello")))
  (is= clojure.lang.Symbol (spyx (type 'hello)))

  (is= "to my heart" (ident :hello))
  (is= "like cheese" (ident "hello"))
  (is= "crash, bang" (ident 'hello))
 )
```

with result:

```
----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.1    Java 13-ea
----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
(type :hello) => clojure.lang.Keyword
(type "hello") => java.lang.String
(type (quote hello)) => clojure.lang.Symbol

Ran 2 tests containing 6 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

and if you uncomment the `throw` you will get the symbol listed in any Exception stacktrace like this:

```
ERROR in (dotest-line-19) (core.clj:16)
expected: (clojure.core/= "crash, bang" (ident (quote hello)))
  actual: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: surprise!
{:reason :dont-need-one}
 at tst.demo.core$eval23035$ident_fn_sym__23036.doInvoke (core.clj:16)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:408)
    clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke (MultiFn.java:229)
    tst.demo.core$fn__23039.invokeStatic (core.clj:26)
    tst.demo.core/fn (core.clj:19)
```

Notice that the "function name" is included in the stacktrace as `tst.demo.core$eval23035$ident_fn_sym__23036`.  As with any "anonymous" function, this can be of great use in tracking down the cause of an exception. For example:

```
(dotest
  (let [add2 (fn add2-fn [a b] (+ a b))]
    (is= 5 (add2 2 3))))
```

Here we use `add2-fn` to name the function as a debugging aid in case of an exception.  I like to use a `-fn` suffix as it helps speed `grep`-based searching of source code.

---

### Update:

Here is the info from clojuredocs.org

```
;; Methods can be given a name.  Very useful in stack traces.
(defmethod foo "a" name-of-method [params] "was a")
```

So `name-of-method` is a symbol, not a docstring.

P.S.  Note that, to the user, the fact that a function is implemented as a multi-method (vs a regular function with a `cond` or `if` or something else), is really just a implementation detail.  The contract of the function itself (name, args, purpose, etc) is defined in the `defmulti` form, and that is where the docstring belongs.

Comment: You probably misunderstood me, I meant a docstring as in `(defn something "A documentation" [arg] (do-something))`